# Try to add candlestickseries to shinobiCharts in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, shinobi

I'm novice at Xamarin and I'm trying to use ShinobiCharts in Xamarin.Android to show candlestick data on it. 
Code from .axml:

```
<fragment
            class="com.shinobicontrols.charts.ChartFragment"
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is fragment where should be shown chart.

```
var chartFragment = (ChartFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.chart);
var chart = chartFragment.ShinobiChart;
chart.SetLicenseKey("license_key");

chart.AddXAxis(new DateTimeAxis
            {
                GesturePanningEnabled = true,
                GestureZoomingEnabled = true
            });

chart.AddYAxis(new NumberAxis
            {
                GesturePanningEnabled = true,
                GestureZoomingEnabled = true
            });

var dataPoints =
                quotes.Select(
                    quoteCandle =>
                        new MultiValueDataPoint(DateUtils.ConvertToJavaDate(TimeStamp.UnixToDate(quoteCandle.Timestamp)),
                            (double) quoteCandle.Low, (double) quoteCandle.High,
                            (double) quoteCandle.Open, (double) quoteCandle.Close)).ToList();

var series = new OHLCSeries { DataAdapter = new SimpleDataAdapter() };
series.DataAdapter.AddAll(dataPoints);
chart.AddSeries(series);
chart.XAxis.Style.GridlineStyle.GridlinesShown = true;
chart.YAxis.Style.GridlineStyle.GridlinesShown = true;
chart.RedrawChart();
```

This is code of creating ShinobiCharts.
The problem is that added series are not shown in chart. Style changed, but there are no series. What do I do wrong? I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for question, Candlestickes are not available for trial version of ShinobiControls, only  for premium version.

Comment: The trial version is a trial of the Premium version - you should have access to all the premium features, but only for 30-days.

Answer (score 0):

As sammyd said, CandlestickSeries are available in the trial version of ShinobiCharts for Android (as are all the other premium features). Have you managed to get the CandlestickChart sample running? The sample is included in the download bundle.

On the face of it your code looks fine (without seeing the rest of it) but there are a couple of things I'd recommend checking:

1. Have you replaced the string *license_key* with the trial license key we would have emailed you when you downloaded the bundle? The trial license key is a a really long string of characters and digits.
2. Is your data coming in as expected and does it make sense (e.g. are your low values less than your open values etc.)?
3. I'm not sure it'll make much difference, as they're pretty much interchangeable, but you're actually creating an OHLCSeries in code but mention a CandlestickSeries
4. Have you set the series' style object in a way that would stop it from showing i.e. have you set it to be transparent in colour?
5. Are you getting an actual error, and if so what message is being logged?

Hopefully the above will help you get your candlestick chart up and running!

Edit:

If you're using the Android Emulator, your AVD needs to have GPU emulation turned on (as we use OpenGL ES 2.0 for rendering the charts). There's more information on using the emulator with OpenGL on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

**Disclaimer: I work for ShinobiControls**

Comment: I've tryed to run the CandlestickChart sample and also didn't see any data on chart. And, yes, I replaced license_key by my trial license, data is correct, an OHLCSeries are changed to a CandlestickSeries but it doesn't matter, I didn't set any style to series and I didn't have any error message.

Comment: That is very strange! Would you be able to send an email to info@shinobicontrols.com with a zip of the project you're trying to run (with your trial key inserted)? Also, can you let us know the following: what device you're testing it on, what version of Android it's running, what version of Xamarin.Android you're using, whether you are using Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm testing on 3.7''WVGA Nexus One, Android 4.0.3(v15), Xamarin.Android 4.12, tryed to run applications in Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio, result just the same. Thanks for advice, I send email to support.

Comment: What I've observed on debugging is that when I have 20 elements in dataPoints List after adding it to OHLCSeries via Adapter it display that the count of series is 1.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this, the reason for the count of 1 is that `IShinobiChart.Series.Count` is the number of Series on the Chart (in this case 1). To get the number of data points in a series you need to do something like the following:  `IShinobiChart.Series[0].DataAdapter.Size()`